# How omnet process messages from future event set?

Tags: simulation, omnet++, schedule

Omnet use future event set queue for sending messages in certain time during simulation. I am trying to fully understand how omnet works so I have two questions related to FES.

- Is it FES place where I store msg that will trigger host(module) to start some activities (for example to send msg to some other module)?. I read somewhere that FES is place just for selfMessages, is this correct?
- Other question is related to how FES identify who will receive msg (how identify module) since in scheduleAt(time, msg) there is no identifier of module that generate msg. I search in class cMessage and there is no attribute about module name. So how FES sends that msg in certain time of simulation?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- No. FES contains all messages and events. Self messages and messages to other modules are also stored in the FES.
- `scheduleAt()` is for scheduling a self message, so the target module is the module that actually calls the function. Each `cMessage` object contain a `targetModuleId` that determines, where the message will be delivered.